# Getting values from HTTP POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a legacy system (written in ColdFusion) that posts to my RESTful MVC application, in which I am trying to access the posted parameters.

I was advised to set the content-type header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in the legacy system, and this should mean `controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form.AllKeys` contains the posted parameters, but it does not.

Other Stack Overflow posts have suggested reading the `controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream` but I was wondering if there was a different/easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just setting the request Content-Type header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` might not be sufficient. The client needs also to respect this content type meaning that the body of the POST request must look like this:

```
param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3&...
```

Now you will be able to retrieve individual values using `Request.Form["param1"]`, or simply by using a view model and having your controller action take this view model as parameter, so that you don't need to be manually retrieving those parameters from the request.

If the client doesn't respect the specification your only chance is to read the `Request.InputStream` and parse it manually.

Comment: OK - that makes sense. Do you know how I can (whilst debugging) see what the format of the request is? Is that in Request.InputStream?

Comment: Yes, it's inside `Request.InputStream`. You could read it with a `StreamReader`.

Comment: Turns out that I don't need to set the content-type at all, as long as I pass the parameters through correctly. I was passing them through as `URL` parameters, rather than `FORMFIELD`, so the values are actually in `Request.QueryString` - no parsing of `Request.InputStream` required.